# How to have infinite array in oracle?

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

How use infinite array in Oracle or PL/SQL? And please give me array list in Oracle and when use array in oracle.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Show your effort.

Comment: how write infinite array  for example i write ype in_array IS VARRAY(n) OF VARCHAR2(40000);and no ansewr

Answer (score 3):

Strictly, infinite arrays are impossible, because they have to fit in private sessions memory, and that's not unlimited.

If what you mean is simply "unbounded" then use a nested table or associative array type:

```
declare
   type my_nt is table of varchar2(128) 
        index by binary_integer;
   l_coll my_nt;
begin
   l_coll(1) := 'This is a test';
   l_coll(128) := 'Go for it';
end;
/
```

[Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#BABFACFA).

---

There are no arrays or array lists in Oracle PL/SQL, so I'm not sure what you're thinking of.